# Catch the moment when a callback asyncrounous function has finished

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have this code to render a select file for uploading:

```
  //1
  <input type="file" multiple id="my_html_uploader" />


//2
var files = myHtmlUploaderElem.files;
if (files.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0, file1; file1 = files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(file2, i2) {
      return function(e) {
        alert("done!");
      };
    })(file1, i);

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
```

How can I catch the moment when the callback of **reader.onload(...)** has been finished for

a) an individul file

b) all the file what have been selected

?

Comment: For part B, create a global variable with the length of your array.  Each time your onload callback executes subtract one from the counter, and check if it's zero.  if so, do your final callback.  That is what Promise.All does.

Answer (score 0):

Create Promises, then you can use `Promise.all` to await them all:

```
const promises = []; // keep as much constant as possible

for (const file of files) { // way more beautiful, no need for an IIFE with "const" or "let"
  let reader = new FileReader();

  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // short for: function(resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  }));

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  alert("all loaded");
  // results is an array of file contents
}).catch(error => {
  // one of the files failed to load, handle that here
});
```

Comment: will that work in all the browsers, including the old ones?

Comment: No, it won't. Transpile it back to ES5 to get better support.

Comment: How to do that in ES5?